# How can I call a library function in an other library not directly connected to it?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

This is my example, I have `main.c`, that `dlopen`s `lib1.so` and is linked to `lib2.so` at linking time.
`lib1.so` needs to call a function defined in `lib2.so`, something like this:

main.c

```
extern void func2();

int main(){
   void *handle;
   void (*lib1)();

   handle = dlopen("./lib1.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   *(void**)(&lib1) = dlsym(handle, "lib1");
   if(!lib1){
       printf("Can't find lib1\n");
   }
   else{
       func1();
       dlclose(handle);
   }
   //func2();
   return 0;
}
```

lib1.c

```
extern void func2();

void func1(){
    printf("Function1\n");
    func2();
}
```

lib2.c

```
void func2(){
    printf("Function2\n");
}
```

I compile main as I sad before

```
gcc -rdynamic main.c -o main lib2.so -ldl
```

but when I run `main` I get `undefined symbol: lib2`, but if I remove the comment `//func2()` in `main.c` (so I simply call `func2()` at least one time in `main`), the program works and `lib1` is able to call `func2()`.
Why can't I call `func2()` in `lib1` without calling it also in `main`, is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to [--as-needed](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Quality_Assurance/As-needed) linker option being enabled by default in all modern Linux distros. Linker realizes that main module does not use anything from `lib2.so` and ignores `-llib2` option. To force `lib2.so` linkage you can either insert a fake reference to one of it's functions (as you suggested) or simply disable `--as-needed` when linking `lib2.so`:

```
gcc ... -Wl,--no-as-needed lib2.so -Wl,--as-needed
```

Another meaningful solution would be to link `lib1.so` against `lib2.so`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, it's enough to force the linking using `-Wl,--no-as-needed`, thank's a lot.